# Is a void function possible on a null instance?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a little demo of the internet for a school project and I decided to do this in Java, because that is the language I have the most experience with and have done most of my work in.

So I created a `type` of `DNS`, for Domain Name Systems. I also created a `Table`, to store url's and locations in. 
See the following code:

Class Table:

```
public class Table {

    private String url;
    private DNS dns;

    public Table(){
    }

    public String getURL(){ //Return url of a server
        return this.url;
    }

    public void add(Something something){
        //Some code to add something
    }
}
```

Class DNS:

```
public class DNS {

    private Table[] table = new Table[50];

    public DNS(){
        //Some code here
    }

    public void add(Something something){ //Add a server to the DNS' table

        int i = 0;
        while(this.table[i].getURL() != null){ //NullPointerException
            i++;
        }
        this.table[i].add(something);
    }
}
```

If I want to use the `void add()` from the DNS class, I have to know what the next empty place in `table` is. So I try to retrieve some `url`'s, and if it says the `url == null`, I know I have an empty place.
However I get a `NullPointerException` at `while(this.table[i].getURL() != null){`. This made me wonder if it is possible to `return` a variable that is `null`. Is this possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Wait, are you asking why you get NPE or if it's possible to return something if your method is declared with `void`?

Comment: a void method `public void getURL()` can't return a value. Is it a typo?

Comment: Shouldn't your test be `this.table[i] != null ?`

Comment: @Eran That is a typo, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized the `table` array, but haven't initialized any of its members, so they are all `null`.
You could, for example, do this in the constructor:

```
public DNS(){
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
        table[i] = new Table();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this worked. I never thought of this because I don't do it with a `String[]`, but I guess with a `String[]` this is done in it's constructor, am I right?

Comment: `new String[50]` would also give you an array of 50 `null`s.

Comment: That makes sense, and because I check for a field of a `null` instance, I get `null` returned, because the instance is `null`, and thus the field as well. I get it now! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For your use case, it is far easier to use a `java.util.List`.  In fact, I would recommend the  `java.util.ArrayList`.

It is like an array, except that it can grow.

There are problems with the `table[i]` approach, because in your current code setup, you don't properly detect that maximum i, and as such, you walk past the end of your array.  To fix it an array way, you would use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
   // now we will loop between 0 and the last element of the array.
   ... table[i] ...
}
```

Where the `ArrayList` shows it's flexibility is when it comes time to add to the array.  If I have an array of size 10, and I want to add an 11th element to it, the array is full.  Assuming that I was using a real array, I would need to

1. Create a new array with a size greater than or equal to 11.
2. Copy each element from the old array to the new array, at the correct array index.
3. Copy in the 11th element at the right place.

`ArrayList` does something functionally equivalent to all of this within it's `add(...)` method.  As a result, the code you will eventually write to add items to your table, with look more like this

```
table.add(item);
```

In addition to making it easier to add items, an `ArrayList` will make it easier to remove items.  Without it, generally you will have to write some code to move items into the hole made in the middle of your array, should you every remove an entry.

Comment: Does an `ArrayList` except multiple types, as in my case `DNS` and `String`? @EdwinBuck

Comment: Yes, an `ArrayList<Object>` can hold any Object.

Answer (score 0):

A variable which is null can be returned, but you could simple check if `this.table[i] != null.`